# Launching thread that start as soon as semaphore is released

Tags: c++, multithreading, semaphore

I'm trying to use threading and semaphore to fix a performance problem in my application.

**Problem 1:**

The user click on some checkbox. Each time a checkbox is clicked, a somewhat intensive saving is done in the database. The users complaint that is was slow. So now, when they click on the checkbox, I just launch a thread that do the saving (without waiting for the thread to finish). That was ok for a short while.

**Problem 2:**

When the user is fast and unlucky, sometimes the saving in the database crash because at the same time, the other thread is trying to save in the exact same table. So I think that what we need here is semaphore, **but I'm not sure**.

What I want is this to happen:

User click on checkbox 1
Launch thread 1
User click on checkbox 2
Launch thread 2 (wait for thread 1 to finish)
thread 1 finish
thread 2 finish

Here is my code:

The function we call to launch the thread

```
bool SampleSO::ExecuteThreadSauvegarde()
{
    //Créer le thread
    CWinThread* pThreadSauvegarde = AfxBeginThread(ExecuteThreadSauvegarde, this, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED);
    if(pThreadSauvegarde)
    {
        pThreadSauvegarde->m_bAutoDelete = TRUE;
        pThreadSauvegarde->ResumeThread();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then the function who is called by the previous function (static)

```
UINT SampleSO::ExecuteThreadSauvegarde(LPVOID pParam)
{
    SampleSO* pSampleSO = (SampleSO*)pParam;

    LONG dwSemCount;
    HANDLE hSemaphore = OpenSemaphore( SYNCHRONIZE |SEMAPHORE_MODIFY_STATE, FALSE, _T("Sauvegarde") );

    //this is the function that call the saving
    pSampleSO->Sauvegarde();

    ReleaseSemaphore(hSemaphore, 1, &dwSemCount);

    return 1;
}
```

How can I modify my code so that the critical section is only accessed one thread at the time and that the thread that are waiting for the semaphore go in the critical section as soon as it's released (one at the time).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is not so many threads.  Instead, spawn a single worker thread to deal with DB operations.  When the user clicks, simply post a message/command via a queue to the worker thread.  The worker simply waits for a command, executes it, and goes back to blocking-waiting on the queue.  This will require no synchronization beyond thread-safety for the queue itself, which will be trivial because it's single-producer, single-consumer.

Comment: Do you have some sample code of how such worker thread should work?

Comment: Basically `while (canRun) { doWork(queue.pop()); }`.  You can set `canRun` (a volatile bool) to false from the main thread when you want to shut down, then join() the worker thread to make sure any pending items complete.

Comment: I will look at this solution (may take some time because I'm not very familiar with threading). Will mark your answer as the good one later this week if it works.

Comment: I mark this as the answer (because it "fix" the problem) but right now, my application take 25% of the cpu (one complete core!!) because of the infinite loop of the worker thread, which is BAD! Any idea about how to fix this?

Comment: Sure, make the worker thread block on a condition variable that notifies when the queue is not empty.  You don't need to spin reading the queue; in my toy example code I assumed `queue.pop()` would block until the queue had something to read.